# First order logic deduction

Tags: first-order-logic

I have the following formula.

$\forall X (X=A \Rightarrow x \in X)$

I think this just means that $x \in A$ (right?), but I can't provide a formal proof. Can anyone help me understand which tools I should be using?

Comment: Welcome to MSE: Pleae use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: What are $x$ and $A$?

Comment: $x$ and $A$ are sets... what I'm trying to say is that I suspect what I wrote is a different way of writing $x \in A$, but I can't prove it formally.

Comment: $\in$ is not part of the language of "pure" first-order logic: it needs set theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a formal proof along the lines as suggested by @TannerSwett:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> I think this just means that $x \in A$ (right?), but I can't provide a formal proof.

That's correct. So the statement that you need to prove is:

$$\forall X (X = A \implies x \in X) \iff x \in A$$

The way to prove this is by proving that $\forall X (X = A \implies x \in X) \implies x \in A$, and also proving that $x \in A \implies \forall X (X = A \implies x \in X)$.

#### Forward direction

You may assume that $\forall X (X = A \implies x \in X)$, and you must prove that $x \in A$. Use universal instantiation here.

#### Backward direction

You may assume that $x \in A$, and you must prove that $\forall X (X = A \implies x \in X)$. Start by proving that $X = A \implies x \in X$, and then use universal generalization.

---

I hope this provides a step in the right direction. How far can you go from here? Do you have any questions about this?

Comment: Thanks, it does look like a step in the right direction. Regarding the forward direction, the idea that I have from what you said is to use universal instantiation and take $X=A$. This way, I'd have $A=A \Rightarrow x \in A$ and since $A=A$ is always true by the axiom of reflexivity, I can conclude that $x \in A$ has to be true for the whole formula to hold.

Comment: Regarding the backward direction, I suppose that if $x \in A$, $X=A$ implies that $x \in X$ because I can use the axiom of substitution. So, $X=A \Rightarrow x \in X$ must be true. Then, I can use generalisation to add the $\forall X$ in front.
Does all this make any sense?

Comment: @Thecuriousamateur Yes, all of that is completely correct!